# how to create a custom module for overriding the core functionality in drupal with hook_user_login?

Tags: php, module, drupal, hook, drupal-8

I have created a module with a .info file and .module file for implementing the hook_user_login

```
 function custom_login_user_login(UserInterface $account) {
      $config = \Drupal::config('system.date');
      drupal_set_message("helello");
    }
```

//module name is custom_login
i have used the xdebugger to track wheather this is working,but the function is not firing, giving me error once i have logged into the system

Comment: What error did you get?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 function custom_login_user_login(Drupal\user\UserInterface $account) {
      $config = \Drupal::config('system.date');
      drupal_set_message("helello");
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).